# Algorithm to find a polyhedral embedding

Tags: ds.algorithms, reference-request, co.combinatorics, topological-graph-theory

A polyhedral embedding of a graph on a surface is an embedding without edge crossings such that all the faces are bounded by simple cycles, and any two faces share a common vertex, share a common edge, or do not intersect at all.

I need an algorithm that, given a graph, finds a polyhedral embedding if the graph admits it. I have been looking around but haven't found it. I also need to know the time order of the algorithm.

Deciding whether a graph admits a polyhedral embedding is NP-complete (proved here: B. Mohar, Existence of polyhedral embeddings of graphs, Combinatorica 21 (2001), 395–401, http://www.fmf.uni-lj.si/~mohar/Papers/Fw3npc.pdf). I don't expect an efficient algorithm, just something that works.

**Note**: I should mention that I am only interested in the combinatorial aspect of this problem. An embedding of a graph can be described by specifying the cyclic orderings of the edges incident on any vertex, and a signature for each edge, which is +1 or -1 according to whether the cyclic orderings of the two vertices on this edge are consistent along this edge. A face-walk is a walk in the graph where at all vertices the next edge is the leftmost edge according to the cyclic ordering on the vertex. A polyhedral embedding is an embedding where all the face-walks are simple cycles. The problem is then to find a circular ordering of edges around each edge and a signature for each edge such that all face-walks are simple cycles.

Comment: You could just enumerate all possible cyclic rotations and check whether or not the resulting embedding is polyhedral. Hey, you didn't say you had to have an efficient algorithm.

Comment: @TimothySun We'll call that 'plan B' ;)

Comment: does the surface have an arbitrary dimension? isnt it easier to find an embedding as the dimension of the surface goes up?

Comment: @vzn I am refering to closed surfaces, where a surface is a compact, connected 2-manifold.

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't this give you what you want?  Because you only care about the combinatorics, your problem is to embed a graph in a surface, I gather a surface of genus zero.

> Bojan Mohar, "Embedding graphs in an arbitrary surface in linear time," *STOC* 1996 ([ACM link](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=237986)).

Comment: I need to find a **polyhedral** embedding, if it exists.

Comment: (See the beginning of my question for a definition of polyhedral embedding.) I think that the paper you suggest will only find an embedding in a surface of given genus, if it exists. Nothing guarantees that the embedding will be polyhedral.

Comment: @becko: I guess I simply do not understand.  Your definition of a polyhedral embedding looks to me like an embedding in a surface. There is no geometry, just cycles and incidence.  I'll let others clear up my confusion.

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke: Faces in an embedding don't have to be simple cycles.

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke: "Polyhedral" means the closure of every face is a closed disk, and every pair of closed faces intersects in a single edge, in a single vertex, or not at all.  Embeddings in which a single face is incident to both sides of an edge, or incident to a vertex multiple times, or in which two faces share more than one vertex, are not polyhedral.  Mohar's algorithm computes a _cellular_ embedding, meaning every face is an open disk, but that's a much weaker condition.

Comment: Thanks Timothy and JeffE.  I see now.  Sorry for misunderstanding.